# Kestrel error: address already in use (dotnet core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

Summary: it works as `dotnet run`, but it doesn't work as `dotnet myappname.dll`.

My linux skills are limited, but I am trying to go by the book so I don't mix things up (following [this tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx) from Scott Hanselman):

```
$ cd /home/myusername/dotnettest
$ dotnet run
```

> Now listening on: http://localhost:5123

Then I move it to /var like so:

```
$ sudo cp -a /home/myusername/dotnettest/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish /var/dotnettest
```

Finally I test if it works there as well:

```
$ dotnet dotnettest.dll
```

Then it fails:

```
info: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/home/myusername/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.GetSockIPEndPoint()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WebApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/myusername/dotnettest/Program.cs:line 27
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've been careful in trying to stop nginx.

I've checked if anything is listening to :5123 with the command:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:5123
```

And nothing seems to come up.

Comment: After a `sudo netstat -ltp` I've seen that there was a `dotnet` process permanently listening to :5000 (I left something running? I don't think there's a default background process doing that). So then I retry `dotnet dotnettest.dll` and it works... but it listens to :5000 (instead of :5123). I'll have to check what I did wrong, but looks like it's taking into account the changes I made in `Program.cs` (it's weird because `dotnet run` was listening to :5123 as expected).

Answer (score 26):

The following command help to find the port and kill the process

Terminal on mac

find the process number

```
lsof -i: <port number>
```

eg lsof -i:5001

Then kill the process number

```
kill -9 <process number>
```

eg - kill -9 1600

Answer (score 5):

I know the OP is on a Mac, but this question pops up as the first Google result, so I'm adding a Windows workaround too:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5001).OwningProcess
```

Run the above in powershell/windows terminal (replace `5001` with your port number). Then kill the process by running:

```
kill theProcessNumberHere
```

Comment: Thanks man - but would have been even more helpful if you included the line to kill the process - even though its simply kill #:D - i forgot it was that easy and had to google it!

Comment: I went through so many solutions and this one was easy.  It would have helped to explain exactly which number was the process number in Get-Process -ID, but I guessed it was ID and it worked.  THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

in linux/mac

```
ps aux | grep "dotnet"
```

Find the process and then run

```
kill -9 <process_id>
```

Answer (score 2):

VS2019 - In my case, I was able to work around this by changing the port Kestrel was using.  Here are two options that worked for me (pick one):

1. Add an "applicationUrl" setting to the launchSettings.json file (found under the Properties folder in VS2019).  Using "https://localhost:5201" in the example below:

   ```
   "profiles": {
     "IIS Express": {
         ...
         "environmentVariables": {
           "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
         },
       "Host": {
         ...
       }
     },
     "Your.App.Namespace.Api": {
       ...
       "environmentVariables": {
         "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
       },
       "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5201;http://localhost:5200"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add a "UseUrls" fluent method invocation to the WebHostBuilder in Program.Main().  i.e. "http://localhost:5200/" in the example below:

   ```
   using (var host = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseKestrel(o => o.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
   ...
   .UseStartup<Startup>()
   .UseUrls("http://localhost:5200/")
   ```

Comment: I have heavy load so I had to add a few more extra ports in the applicationUrl : if launchsettings.json, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was not correctly rebuilt after changing the `Program.cs` configuration to listen to :5123. And the published version was using :5000 instead of :5123.

At the same time, the port :5000 was being used by a different `dotnet` process (which I found through `sudo netstat -ltp` and killed afterwards). That's why the error was "address already in use". After killing the process, `dotnet dotnettest.dll` ran OK but at port :5000 (not :5123 yet).

I then made sure the project was correctly rebuilt, I deleted the `/publish` folder just in case, then `dotnet publish`. Important note: **I had to copy `hosting.json` manually to the built folder** (also to the publish folder afterwards). Now it's listening to :5123.

---

Steps:

- Make sure you don't have any other process listening to the default port (:5000), using `sudo netstat -ltp`.
- Make sure the project is properly rebuilt, and includes the new configuration listening to :5123 (for this you have to include `hosting.json` in your project, so it is copied at build and publish).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using ASP.NET CORE 3.1 my app was kind enough to write the port number and I confirmed that it is not used. The exception was thrown because I had used `ListenAnyIP()` for my heroku version of the app, but then when I deployed the app on premise behind reverse proxy, my firewall kicked in as the port was not meant to be open.